# Leaflet - drawing semitransparent canvas tiles over map

Tags: javascript, canvas, leaflet

I'm extending Leaflet's [GridLayer](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/tile/GridLayer.js) to show canvas tiles on which I draw some data points - the problem is that after zooming in and out the other zoom layers are still visible, or are partially chopped off in random ways.

E.g. on the left is zoom level 13, on the right is after zooming out to 11 and back to 13 -

[image]

How can I show only the current zoom level, and prevent the canvas tiles from getting chopped off?

Comment: Seeing some code and ideally a live reproduction case would surely help.

Comment: @ghybs see below - I actually meant to self-answer this but I hit enter on the tag list and it submitted the question

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up fixing it, though there might be better ways...

Here's my GridCanvas class -

```
L.GridLayer.GridCanvas = L.GridLayer.extend({

  onAdd: function (map) {
    L.GridLayer.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);
    map.on('zoomend', e => this.onZoomEnd(e.target._zoom));
  },

  // on zoom end, want to hide all the tiles that are not on this zoom level,
  // and show all the ones that are
  onZoomEnd: function (zoom) {
    Object.values(this._levels).forEach(level => {
      level.el.style.display = (level.zoom === zoom) ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
  },

  createTile,

});
```

The `visibility` of the tiles also gets set in seemingly random ways - this seemed to fix the problem - adding a class to the canvas elements and setting them to always be visible -

```
function createTile(coords, done) {
  const canvas = L.DomUtil.create('canvas', 'grid-canvas-tile');
  ...
}
```

with styles.css:

```
.grid-canvas-tile {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```